# Matplotlib figure pdf save to pass IEEE graphics analyzer

Tags: pdf, matplotlib, ieee

When I save figure like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
plt.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42

plt.plot(t1, t1, color='g', label='plot')
plt.legend(loc='best', fontsize = 14, fancybox=True, framealpha=0.2, 
frameon=False)
plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=12)
plt.savefig('images/test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', format='pdf', dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

and analyze with on line IEEE Graphics analyzer tool (http://graphicsqc.ieee.org/reports/5965c1e4c7ca176031474bc8/edit)

I get the following error:

*Your graphic may contain fonts that are not embedded into the file, or text outlines that may not available*

When the same pdf is just opened in photoshop and saved as pdf, the new pdf goes through the check without any errors.

Does anyone have idea how to do that directly in savefig?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to create a minimal example of the issue. Is this analyzer tool available online and available for use? Can you link to it? I do not have photoshop; does photoshop pdf saving preserve the vectorized pdf or does it create a pixel image out of it?